# Error 400 when connecting Notion API to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, rest, notion-api

I'm trying to connect the Notion API to Power BI using the web connector in Power BI.  Here is a screenshot of the setup and the error that I'm getting..

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add the version header:
https://developers.notion.com/reference/versioning

Comment: This is definitely a step forward, so thank you..   I'm now getting an error 404.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Did you specifically share the database with your integration?

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Besides informing Authorization, Notion-version, you might need to add

```
#"Content-Type" = application/json
```

In addition, it seems you're querying a database. Therefore, you'll follow this [official link](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query). For more info, check my own [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Notion/comments/rh8pgq/notion_with_power_bi_connection/) about it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the 400 error despite having all the required headers in my request.

Specifically, I was attempting to create a new page in my database using the 'https://api.notion.com/v1/pages' endpoint.

The root cause of the issue was traced back to a discrepancy in the **data type of one of my database properties** compared to the type I was trying to use during the creation my request.

Comment: I hope sharing this experience will provide valuable insights for anyone facing a similar challenge.